# Simple Blitz 3D Basic code not functioning for my web app

Tags: web-applications, timer, blitz++

I am developing an application on Blitz 3D that uses basic programming language. Look at this code:

```
If MilliSecs() = timer + 1000 Then pitch#=2 yaw#=2 roll#=2
If MilliSecs() = timer + 2000 Then pitch#=3 yaw#=3 roll#=3
If MilliSecs() = timer + 3000 Then pitch#=4 yaw#=4 roll#=4
```

As you can see, I want to make an animation that changes every second. The problem is that it will animate the first one and the last one, but not the middle on. I have tried adding more lines and its always the same issue. I do not understand what I am doing wrong here and would appreciate any assistance in solving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Rather adding the MilliSecs() & timer try the code below:

```
pitch#=2
yaw#=2
roll#=2

;add your RotateEntity command here example: RotateEntity cone,pitch#,yaw#,roll#

Delay(1000)

pitch#=3
yaw#=3
roll#=3

;add your RotateEntity command here example: RotateEntity cone,pitch#,yaw#,roll#

Delay(1000)

pitch#=4
yaw#=4
roll#=4

;add your RotateEntity command here example: RotateEntity cone,pitch#,yaw#,roll#
```